# Magento 2 Very slow loading images

Tags: magento2, product-images

I'm running Magento 2.3 on CentOS with 8GB RAM, SSD, 4 Core CPU approx 6,000 products each with 3 or more images. CDN is also running.

I've gone through every possible option within Magento and in the server to get the best possible speeds but the images on the site still load very slow.

There's an image optimizer that's always running by Cron and I can see it has reduced the quality and file size of most images.

The site is [terabytecomponents.co.uk](https://www.terabytecomponents.co.uk) and if you click on any category from the menu, you will see what i mean and this relates to the product list page, product page and quick view.

This is a temporary fix as it'll load one image first whilst the rest loads: 
[xumulus/magento2](https://github.com/xumulus/magento2-fast-product-images) but not curing the problem.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: Awaiting your data for analysis.

Comment: If you could post any of the additional information requested, some suggestions could be provided for you to consider.